# What is the difference between Ignore and skip in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

What is the difference between ignore and skip in TestNG?

(enabled=false)

and

dependsOnMethod={"testNG"}

Answer (score 0):

Ignore means do not run it at all, and skip with the combinations of Listeners can be use for listening dependent methods and/or test. So let assume you have dependency between two tests and /or methods, test 2 can be performed only if test 1 pass.
Skip will hapen for test 2 if test 1 fails.